# Problem when socket_setup call fcntl(sock, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)

Tags: c, windows, cross-platform, pgbouncer

I try to make pgbouncer in windows

They have `usual` library (libusual) for work with ip-sokets.

When pgbouncer tune socket, it calls `socket_setup` from usual library

`socket_setup` call 
    `res = fcntl(sock, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);`
and `res` is -1 now.

How can I fix one?

My build system is mingw64 from msys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for someone who find this page.

Problem occurred because the `usual` library in some (not in all) places use `int` instead `SOCKET` which is `int*` and has a size more than size of `int` on a 64-bit platform.